# Is there any Ruby test framework that supports a system under test that is asynchronous

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, asynchronous, system-testing, reactive

I want to be able to test a system where I start a process and the system under test will then message back asynchronously when the process is finished.   I want the test framework to wait for a response and then assert on the correctness of the response or timeout and fail if a response is not received within a certain timeframe.  *Is there a test framework that will do this?*

In my specific case, I am waiting for a websocket publish to tell me that the process under test has finished - but I don't think the particular asynchronous messaging protocol is important.

Comment: No answer.  Maybe there isn't one.

Comment: Message back to what, exactly? A particular method on a particular object, or calling a proc that's passed in, or...? (Could you post a code example of what you think this might look like?)